# input radio not updating the model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a directive that uses a template, and after using this directive, the input type=radio is not updating the model anymore. Normal text-types work ok.

What should I do to keep the model updating?

```
app.directive('advformInput', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 1002,
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            template: [
                '<div class="advform-input form-group">',
                '   <label class="advform-lbl">',
                '       <input class="form-control" />',
                '       <div class="helper" ng-show="advformInput">{{ advformInput }}</div>',
                '   </label>',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            scope: {
                advformInput: '@'
            },
            link: function ($scope, tElement, tAttrs, $ctrls) {
                var ar = ['type', 'name', 'ng-model', 'value'];
                var block = tElement, inp = tElement.find('input');

                $scope.field = tAttrs.advformInput;

                tElement.removeAttr('advform-input')

                // transfer some attributes to the real input
                _.each(ar, function(val, key){
                    inp.attr(val, block.attr(val))
                    block.removeAttr(val)
                })

                // add the type of the input to the div like a class
                block.addClass('inp-' + inp.attr('type'));

                //$compile(inp)($scope);
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
The error was that I wasn't puting the Type and the NgModel in the scope of the directive.
I was removing and adding attributes on my own.
Didn't know how to correctly use the scope.

Here is the question in SO that helped me with this:

[How do I properly build an AngularJS labeled radio input directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122724/how-do-i-properly-build-an-angularjs-labeled-radio-input-directive)

Answer (score 1):

There is no any issue with binding, I think you are trying to pass `true` & `false` value to the directive with `@` is the problem.

**Lets go into depth of the issue.**

Your directive isolated scope binding is using `advformInput: '@'},` which means that you wanted to use `one way binding`. But then when you passed value from directive element, `advformInput` value gets converted to string rather than keeping the `dataType` of that value as `Boolean`.

Likewise here you are passing value from attribute as `advform-input="{{myBoolValue}}"` if its `true`(Bool) then received as `"true"`(string), when it is `false` then `"false"`.

So inside your directive template while evaluation `ng-show` directive value is been passed as a `string` in both cases. That's why `ng-show="someString"` is always going to be true.

**Code**

```
scope: {
    advformInput: '=' //`=` for pass value with two way binding also conserves dataType.
},
```

So my suggestion would be convert `@` binding to `=` for conserving type of parameter while passing it to directive.

If you really care about the one way binding of the directive then you need to change `ng-show` directive expression as below.

```
ng-show="advformInput == 'true'"
```